# WKInterfaceMap does not Load Map

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am building an Apple Watch App, with should place a pin in a map position, I am using the Xcode simulator, but the map just does not load...

[image]

Here is my sample code, there is some other kind of settings that I am missing?

```
import WatchKit
import MapKit

class MapController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet var map: WKInterfaceMap!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        let centerOfMap = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -3.743205, longitude: -38.514871)
        let pinPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -3.65, longitude: -38.514871)
        let coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(1, 1)

        self.map.addAnnotation(pinPosition, withPinColor: .Red)
        self.map.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: centerOfMap, span: coordinateSpan))
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run the app in real device?

Comment: Maybe it is a simulator problem. Don't you have access to ANY device of your friends? You could make a temporary provisioning profile for that device.

Comment: Yeah, I will test with TestFlight, I believe its  a simulator problem, but I am asking here to be sure if I am not making any silly mistake.

Comment: I don't see any silly mistake. Maybe other people could recognize that. I just have a question: Are you sure those coordinates exist on map? I mean, maybe it loads the map, but it is an empty area or an area which is not added to Apple Maps, and then the map seems to be unloaded.

Comment: Yes, https://www.google.com/maps/@-3.769365,-38.510857,12z?hl=en

Comment: So, I just think it is caused of Simulator. Have you taken a look to Location Settings in Simulator? I'm pretty sure they exist in iOS Simulator, but not sure for watchOS Simulator. You can enable or disable location services. And the another problem is that, Apple Watch doesn't have GPS on its own, even in the Simulator. Maybe you should open the accompanying iPhone Simulator too.

Comment: I know this is old but my watch has just started doing this, its not only limited to my app though, even the Apple Maps app doesn't load the tiles correctly. I've tried a restart and a re-install, guess I may have to wipe it and start again, I'm on the latest watchOS 3.1.1

Comment: @Plasma, at the time, I notice this was a bug in the simulator, with no available solution.

Answer (score 1):

It does not load map tiles for simulator. You'll have to test it on the actual watch.